# Variables change before onAnimationEnd runs

Tags: java, android, animation

My problem is most likely because of bad design, but anyway :

I have an ArrayList that holds a bunch of ImageViews (terrain blocks).
Then, I iterated through to create the ImageViews programatically, and then set their animation to an animation called `moveLeft` which just makes the ImageView move left for 10 seconds.

Right after the animation ends, I need to set the ImageView's visibility to GONE because it will be off-screen by then.
The problem is that I used an `int count` to hold the total number of ImageViews.

```
moveLeft.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                terrainArray.get(count - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

I'm constantly making new terrain blocks, which means my count variable is constantly changing.

However, onAnimationEnd doesn't run with the same value of count as it does when the animation starts. As a result, it ends up setting some othhe block's visibility to `GONE` instead.

This is because onAnimationEnd didn't actually run until 10 seconds AFTER the block was created, because the animation lasts 10 seconds.

As a result, I'm left with the wrong block number when I want to set its visibility because MORE blocks are being created AS the animation is running. (therefore increasing `count`'s value)

Is there some sort of way I could store `count`'s current value on the `onAnimationStart` method 
and then pass that same value to the `onAnimationEnd` method? (And make it work for up to infinite numbers of terrain blocks? Also, there's only one listener, and multiple blocks can possibly end their animation at the same time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy. If you are sure that you need the exact value of `count` that is at the `onAnimationStart()`, then create a variable in the anonymous class. Save count value in `onAnimationStart()` and use it in `onAnimationEnd()`

You can copy the following snippet.

```
moveLeft.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        private int mCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            mCount = count;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            terrainArray.get(mCount - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps. But, I am afraid there could be bigger design problems. Be careful boss :)